# How to exclude holidays like saturday, sunday from date using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've found this code online to return the next working day and exclude weekends.

```
function nextWorkDay() {
    const date = new Date();
  do {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  } while (!(date.getDay() % 6));
  return date;
}
```

However, the `% 6` part in my understanding excludes Saturdays and Sundays.
How can I modify it to only exclude Saturdays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getDay` returns a value between 0 and 6, inclusive. 0 is Sunday.

So, `date.getDay() % 6` will result in 0 if `getDay` returns either 0 or 6.

Don't use modulo - use `===` to exclude exactly one day, not both zero and another day.

```
} while (date.getDay() === 6);
```

You also don't need a loop anymore - a single condition will be clearer.

```
function nextWorkDay() {
    const date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    if (date.getDay() === 6) date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    return date;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, just the answer I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would say always go to next day, and if it's Saturday jump to the next day. The sample working code is attached below.

```js
const days = ["SUN", "MON", "TUS", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT"]

function getNextWorkingDate() {
  let now =  new Date();
  let today = new Date(now.setDate(now.getDate() +  1)) // find next day
  // Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, ... (See below):
  if(today.getDay() == 7) { //  if staturday, jump one more day
    today = today.setDate(today.getDate() +  1)
  }
  return today;
}



const nextWorkigDay = getNextWorkingDate();
console.log(nextWorkigDay);
console.log(days[nextWorkigDay.getDay()]);
```